# Hacer un histograma de cada sitio polimórfico

Tags: r

Tengo un data frame como este:

```
          Position    BP    Amaranthus        Anchusa
             1         A       NA                NA
             2         T       T(2)/C(1)         T(2)/C(3)
             3         C       NA                C(3)/G(2)
             4         A       NA                NA
             5         A       A(1)/G(2)         NA
             6         G       NA                NA
             7         G       A(3)              NA
             8         C       C(1)/G(2)         C(2)/G(3)
             9         T       NA                NA
            10         A       NA                A(2)/T(2)/C(1)
```

Me gustaría hacer un histrograma para cada spp (Amaranthus por un lado y Anchusa por otro) donde el eje x sea la posición/BP (solo de aquellos lugares sin NA) y que el eje y sea la frecuencia con la que aparece cada letra. Por ejemplo para Amaranthus que en el eje x que aparezca 4 posiciones/BP y en el eje y aparezcan 7 barras. Estas 7 barras que estén separadas por cada posición; 2 barras juntas para la posición 2 con su frecuencia determinada, 2 para la posición 5, 1 para la posición 7 y 2 para la posición 8.

¿Cómo podría hacerlo?
Muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Siguiendo la detallada descripción del gráfico creo que se podría hacer así:

## Generar los datos

```
library(tiyverse)
tribble(~Position, ~BP,    ~Amaranthus,        ~Anchusa,
1 ,        'A',       NA         ,       NA,
2 ,        'T',       'T(2)/C(1)' ,       'T(2)/C(3)',
3 ,        'C',       NA         ,       'C(3)/G(2)',
4 ,        'A',       NA         ,       NA,
5 ,        'A',       'A(1)/G(2)' ,        NA,
6 ,        'G',       NA         ,       NA,
7 ,        'G',       'A(3)'      ,        NA,
8 ,        'C',       'C(1)/G(2)' ,        'C(2)/G(3)',
9 ,        'T',        NA         ,       NA,
10,        'A',        NA         ,       'A(2)/T(2)/C(1)') -> datos
```

## Transformación de los datos

Son varios pasos y salen warnigns por los `NA` que produce el primer `separate()`. Eso es porque no todos los `BP` tienen la misma cantidad de información y al separarlo se generarán columnas vacías. Deberías prestar atención por si hay `NA` de otro origen ("reales") en tus datos.

Uso unos nombres no muy significativos (Var1, letra, etc.) porque no sé muy bien a que refieren esos datos. Los podrías cambiar.

```
datos %>% 
  gather(SPP, valor, -Position, -BP) %>%
  unite("Var1", Position, BP) %>% 
  separate(valor, 
           into = paste("col", 1:3, sep = ""),  #Aquí se debería cambiar el número de columnas dependiendo de la cantidad de datos distintos que hay en BP
           sep = "/") %>% 
  gather(key, value, -Var1, -SPP) %>% 
  drop_na() %>% 
  separate(value, into = c( "letra", "frecuencia"), sep = "\\(") %>%  #Hay que escapar los paréntesis con \\ pq son reservados en REGEX
  mutate(frecuencia = str_remove(frecuencia, "\\)")) -> datos_limpios

> head(datos_limpios)
# A tibble: 6 x 5
Var1  SPP        key   letra frecuencia
<chr> <chr>      <chr> <chr> <chr>     
1 2_T   Amaranthus col1  T     2         
2 5_A   Amaranthus col1  A     1         
3 7_G   Amaranthus col1  A     3         
4 8_C   Amaranthus col1  C     1         
5 2_T   Anchusa    col1  T     2         
6 3_C   Anchusa    col1  C     3
```

## Gráfico

Con los datos limpios el gráfico es muy simple:

- Mapeamos a `x` la combinación de `Position` y `BP`
- Un color por cada `letra`, con `position = dodge` eso producirá grupos de columnas.
- `y` se marea a `frecuencia`, que era el número entre paréntesis en cada SPP
- Un panel por cada `SPP`.

  - `scales= free` porque sino quedan implícitos los niveles del factor `Var1` en todos los paneles y hay colomnas de altura 0.

Algo así:

```
datos_limpios %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Var1, fill = letra, y = frecuencia)) + 
    geom_col(position = "dodge") + 
    facet_wrap(~SPP, scales = "free")
```

Queda así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es un gráfico en ggplot2, así que se le pueden hacer los ajustes estéticos usuales.

Comment: Funciona correctamente, muchas gracias =)